# How to publish in Activity Recent block?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In the timeline of facebook there is a block called "Activity Recent".
Some applications, like Stumbleupon, publish news in this block.

So, I want to know what API, I have to use to insert news in this block ( Activity Recent ).

I am using JS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API used is Open Graph, and is located here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Be sure to read all documentation and follow the tutorial linked at the bottom of that page.